# PhpStorm + XAMPP not showing latest PHP version in command line

Tags: php, macos, laravel, xampp, phpstorm

[image: Bottom Left Php5.5]

I am using OSX running on El Capitan and setting up PhpStorm and the Laravel environment has been a nightmare. I created a project setting up Composer and created it with `laravel/laravel` from the options menu.

As you can see in the screen shot, the PHP version says 5.6.31.. but if I type `php -v` in the command line.  It gives me php 5.5 (as shown in the bottom left)

If I type `php -v` in the terminal I also get php 5.6.
`which php` returns me `/usr/local/bin/php`

I originally had a problem where PHP would not upgrade to 5.6.. but I managed to solve this with homebrew.

And if I use terminal and cd into the folder to run `artisan key:generate` and `config:clear` .. I am able to get the Laravel homepage to load (but typing this from the PhpStorm command line does not work).

My understanding is that the command line is pointing to the directory of PHP that came with my Mac? So how do I point it to the upgraded version? Or is the problem something else?

I think this is a strange problem and already a few people I have asked have not been able to solve it (also setting this up is all very new to me).

Comment: This is not a 100% solve but it solves my problem.  Since it was only the command line tools where the wrong php version was being used, I am now using the embedded terminal in phpstorm instead of the command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

what I did is to set an alias on my ~/.bashrc to point `php` command to point to `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`

e.g. `alias php="/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php"`

in your case, you can use your XAMPP's full path to your php binary file as you might have different installation paths.

Comment: I tried `vim ~/.bashrc`  then `alias php="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php5.6.31` , esc , `:wq` , `source ~/.bashrc` .. got nothing.

Comment: `alias php="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php5.6.31"` (make sure you did not missed the closing double quote)

Comment: yes had the double quote.  Sorry just a typo in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add:

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php5.6.31:$PATH
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` (assuming you're running a bash shell). Then just run `source ~/.bash_profile` and it should all work.

Comment: I typed cd sudo nano .bash_profile , added this to the bashprofile export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php5.6.31:$PATH then cntrl+x back to terminal and typed source ~/.bash_profile , restarted phpstorm and still the same problem